# Android realtime output sound processing

Tags: android, audio, text-to-speech, audio-processing

I am building a regional language android app (hindi) with text to speech support.

Android has only female voice for hindi tts. I need a male voice as well.

Is there anyway I can route the sound output of TTS to some audio processor in my app and change certain attributes of the audio to make it sound like male and then make it to come out through speakers?

Changing only the pitch does not help. Hence the need of more explicit processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can install other TextToSpeech engines like Vocalizer, SestekTTS, Acapela, IVona, Svox.. You dont have to use googles service.

Furthermore you cant change the male voice to female voice by changing its values

Comment: But those do not support Hindi language. As far as I know, only Google TTS supports Hindi.